# C programming doubts- function call inside function call

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

find(int x, int y)
{
    return((x<y)?0:(x-y));
}

int main(void) 
{
   int a=find(5,find(5,4));
   printf("%d",a);

   return 0;
}
```

The above program gives output as 4. I ran with different values and learnt that the code snippet is to find minumum of two numbers. But, I can't seem to understand how it is working. Can someone explain it for me? I know how the ternary operator works, I didn't get the function call inside function call part.

Comment: i'm surprised to see nobody advised you to explicitly mention the return type of the `find()` function .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a=find(5,find(5,4));

find(5,4) returns 1

find(5,1) returns 4
```

First the find() function gets executed with 5 and 4 as its paramters. which will cause `x<y` condition to fail and returns `x-y` which is `5-4 =1`

Later you have `find(5,1)` which again makes the `x<y` condition fail returning `5-1` which is `4`

Answer (score 2):

Try to break it.
See it this way.

when you say  `int a=find(5,find(5,4));`
then the find function inside the find function i.e `find(5,4)` returns 1;
Now the resultant value makes it `int a=find(5, 1);`
And when find `find(5,1);` is called it returns 4 :)

Answer (score 1):

What's there to "get"?

The function call is, like any other call, evaluated "inside out". All the argument values must be known before the call is made. So, the second argument is `find(5,4)`, thus that call happens first. Then the value of that call is used as an argument in the second, outer, call.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previously given answers, it is always better to explicitly specify the return type of a function.

Change your `find()` function signature to

```
int find(int x, int y);
```

Next, regarding the function execution order, the flow is `inside-out`, means, the inner function will be executed first, the return value will be used to execute the outer call.

Diagramatically,

```
 int a=find(5,find(5,4));
```

can be decomposed as

```
 int a=find(5,find(5,4));       //consider step 1.0

           |                   /*inner find() executes first, returns 1*/
           V

     int a=find(5, 1 /*result of find(5,4)*/);       //consider step 1.1

                 |                  /*result of inner find() used for outer find()*/
                 V

         int a=find(5, 1));       //consider step 1.2

                 |              /*outer find() executes second, returns 4*/
                 V

               int a= 4;       //consider step 1.3
                               /* value 4 is assigned to a*/
```